# javascript: What is the full syntax of this code?

Tags: javascript, css

I watched a youtube video of a guy who did css animations by activating them through javascript events.

Here is the short-hand version per him, but I need the long-stretched out version so I can specifically target just the transition seconds. I don't want to manipulate the other 3, however they will be necessary but I don't know what the code or syntax is for them either.

```
elem.style.transition = "width 0.0s, ease-in 0s";
```

So what is the full 4 statements for this code? Please I need it! Thank you!

And please don't ask me to use Jquery, as that is not what I need right now. Thank you!

Comment: I think you're looking for jQuery or CSS?

Answer (score 2):

```
transition-property: width;
transition-duration: 0.0s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in;
transition-delay: 0s;
```

[Mozilla says this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

Comment: Not really sure why this got down voted, but I am pretty sure you will get your rep back

Comment: I'm getting serially attacked right now.

Comment: yes I saw your *(now deleted)* question on meta, but don't worry about serial downvotes, flag the one of the post for moderator attention and explain there, It should be reversed.

Comment: Yeah, I followed a link that said as much. It said wait 3 days, so the auto-bot-thing has time to catch it. Should I wait?

Comment: yup, you should. But remember to flag any of your downvoted post for moderator attention, and explain the situation in detail.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I picked on the wrong guy.